# Store file to google photos/drive using link (laravel)

Tags: php, laravel, google-drive-api

I have just created Laravel website and I want to store all image/video files on google drive/photos, currently Store method receives links to those files and stores them into database, I want to upload those video/image files on google drive or photos (photos better) and store google link into database. How can I do this, using google drive API ?

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/filesystem The documentation for Laravel describes the File Storage drivers and how to implement them. A quick search show up https://github.com/Superbalist/laravel-google-cloud-storage as implementation.

Comment: @MattRink Unfortunately I am getting error while installing GCS
Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.

Answer (score 0):

Just a reference for you.

[Uploading Files](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-uploads) in Drive API.

> The Drive API allows you to upload file data when [create or updating a
>   File resource.
>
> You can send upload requests in any of the following ways:
>
> - Simple upload: uploadType=media. For quick transfer of a small file (5 MB or less). To perform a simple upload, refer to Performing a
>     Simple Upload.
> - Multipart upload: uploadType=multipart. For quick transfer of a small file (5 MB or less) and metadata describing the file, all in a
>     single request. To perform a multipart upload, refer to Performing a
>     Multipart Upload.
> - Resumable upload: uploadType=resumable. For more reliable transfer, especially important with large files. Resumable uploads are a good
>     choice for most applications, since they also work for small files at
>     the cost of one additional HTTP request per upload. To perform a
>     resumable upload, refer to Performing a Resumable Upload. Most Google
>     API client libraries implement at least one of the methods. Refer to
>     the client library documentation for additional details on how to use
>     each of the methods.

More info on the docs.